# Unit conversion from km to mm

Tags: homework-and-exercises, unit-conversion

I'm a bit rusty on my unit conversion skills and I need help figuring out what I did incorrectly converting 9.06 x 10^8 km into mm. Here's what I did: 9.06 x 10^8 km x (1 meter/10^3 km) x (10^-3 km/1 m). I'm pretty sure my last step is the incorrect one, but I'm not certain.

Comment: You have written (1 m / 10$^3$ km) which is not true, it is the other way around: (10$^3$ m / 1 km). Not sure what the ( 10$^{-3}$ km / 1 m) bit is about since you're looking for the ratio of m to mm.

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize that! Completely screwed up the conversion factors

Comment: @KyleKanos that should have been an answer, I'd say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$9.06 \times 10^8 km \times \frac{number\, of\, mm\, in\, 1 km}{1 km} = 9.06\times  10^8 km \times \frac{10^6 mm}{1 km} = 9.06\times 10^{14}mm$$

Comment: Oh geez I completely did the whole thing backwards. Thank you for your clarification!!

Answer (score 0):

You ended up multiplying by 1.

$9.06\cdot 10^8 km \times \frac {1000m}{1km}\times \frac {1000mm}{1m}$
$\ \ \ \ \ =9.06\cdot 10^{14}$

Comment: thanks for your help! Now I know i did the problem backwards